# How to quickly scroll to the latest / end of command history in bash?

Tags: bash

Lots of times I'll use Ctrl-R for reverse search and mistype some letter. Bash jumps up hundreds of lines and I'm in the middle of commands I was using a week ago.

Is there a shortcut for jumping back down to the lastest commands I had typed?

Edit: after testing it out on a CentOS server and Mac OS X, it looks like this only happening on OS X.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've struggled with this same issue.

You can solve this by aborting with ctrl-c. Whether you're in the middle of a reverse search or scrolling through history with the arrows, aborting returns you to a prompt with the history scroll just after the last command.

**UPDATE**

Here's a nice trick I just learned. Bash and many other programs use Readline under the hood for command-line interpretation. Key bindings for Readline can be configured in a .inputrc file or with the bind command. The bindings can make use of a few functions provided by Readline. For example, I use Bash in vi mode but I still like to use Emacs-style ctrl-A so I have this line in my .bashrc file:

bind '\C-a:beginning-of-line'

To list all the available Readline functions:
bind -l

Among the functions is end-of-history. The function does like its name suggests. The difference between this approach and just using the abort command is that this keeps you on the same prompt.

Answer (score 4):

If using libreadline, Alt-> (or Meta->). More info on [Readline shortcuts](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts) or search for *Commands for Manipulating the History* in the man page.

Comment: It depends on the shell used, and whether it has support for libreadline or not. Never used iTerm2 myself, check if it has some settings to define the Meta key. BTW, if you are using OS X, this shortcuts work fine in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, try `command + .`
It works for me.
I was trying `alt+.` and `alt+shift+.` , neither works for me. And then found `command + .` actually works

Comment: cmd+. on macOS 12.6 Apple Terminal produces Ctrl-C. So suggestion to look for bindings is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but you can fix your mistyped character(s) by using backspace when you're in the CTRL-r (reverse-i-search) mode.

Comment: Backspace lets me correct it but the search cursor is still 100+ commands up.

Answer (score 0):

You may wan to try "suggest box"-like history [HSTR](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr). It reads the bash history and allows quick navigation and filtering - you can see the context of similar history entries. Once you select a history entry it can be edited on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In Zsh with `emacs` binding set the actual default key sequence is `^[>` binded to `end-of-buffer-or-history` command rather than `command-.` suggested above (or `end-of-history` depending on effect you want to achieve)

`Cmd-.` produces in Apple Terminal the similar or the same key sequence as `Ctrl-C`, which can be confirmed by running something useless and long, e.g. `find . >/dev/null 2>&1` and pressing one and then other keys on keyboard.

`Ctrl-C` forces input to be ended and reset. and history scroll is just a side effect for it.